# Set Asp:button command argument dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it impossible to set CommandArgument Property on the go from .aspx page?
I read it has got something to do with viewstate?

What are  the alternative to send parameter to button click event?

```
<% foreach (var s in person.Where(s => s.TableID == t.TableID)) { %>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" BorderWidth="0" Text="Remove" CommandArgument="<%= s.Person.FirstName %>" oncommand="Button1_Command"  />

 <% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below :

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" BorderWidth="0" Text="Remove" 
CommandArgument='<%# s.Person.FirstName %>' oncommand="Button1_Command"  />
```

Comment: Tried that already. It wont work. It says "s does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Edit your question and add code of model class for s.Person.FirstName

Comment: s.Person.FirstName value are fine. I can loop through it with normal html like  <h4> <%= s.Person.FirstName %> </h4>

Answer (score -1):

Here is the alternative

```
<% foreach (var s in person.Where(s => s.TableID == t.TableID)) { %>

  <input type="button" name="<%= s.Person.FirstName %>" 
  runat="server" value="Remove" onServerClick="Button1_Command" />


   <% } 
%>
```

then on server side

```
 protected void Button1_Command(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {  
    string val = "clicked value is is: "+ ((HtmlInputControl)sender).Name; 
  }
```

Just edited - this will work

Comment: Thks. However, ((HtmlButton)sender).Value is invalid method on server side.

Comment: You can't edit the `name` attribute of a server control. ASP.NET re-maps that name

Comment: @Joe you right - forgot about it. Value can be used for sure